# How to conditionally play an audio clip in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

## Goal

Play an audio clip for navigation whenever the `reactive` value of position is in a certain range

### What I tried

Based on other questions, I found that a button can be used to play an audio clip. For example:

#### An example with action button

```
library(shiny)

addResourcePath("Music", "Music")
audio_file1 <- "Music/in 200 m turn left.mp3"



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  basicPage(
    actionButton("play", "Play the Audio")
  )
  
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$play, {
    insertUI(selector = "#play",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file1, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = NA, controls = NA, style="display:none;")  
    )
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### My modifications without an action button

I want to autoplay the audio clip whenever the position `x` is a certain value. For keeping the question short, I am providing `x` inside `server` in this example:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  x <- 1
  
  observeEvent(if (x==1){return(x)}, {
    insertUI(selector = "#play",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file1, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA, style="display:none;")  
    )
  })
}
```

However, that threw an error:

```
Warning: Error in eval_tidy: no function to return from, jumping to top level
  [No stack trace available]
```

I have also separately tried using the `uiOutput` and `renderUI` as follows (server part):

```
  output$audioo <- renderUI({
    
    if (x > 0.5 & x < 1.5) {
    
    tags$audio(src = audio_file_200_TL, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)  
      
    } else {
      
      tags$h1("My header")
    }
  
    
    })
```

But that plays the audio when the app is just launched and the audio does not play when `x` is in the provided range. How can I conditionally play an audio clip without using an action button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `x` is not an `input` nor a `reactive`. We need this as R process has to know the time to rerun the cycle. There are other hardcore solution which I am not recommending like `shiny::invalidateLater()`.

Try sth like:

```r
x_r <- reactive(x)

observeEvent(x_r(), {
 if (x_r() == 1) {
    insertUI(selector = "#play",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file1, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA, style="display:none;"), immediate = TRUE 
    )
 }
})
```

Btw be very careful with `insertUI`, I do not like to use it as we might add the same element many times. More elegant strategy for me is to add the element by default and later only edit in the DOM, hide/show/edit. we could use `shinyjs` package for such action. `insertUI` often need `immediate = TRUE` argument.

EDIT:

This app is working perfectly for me. The question is what is the `x` in your app. mp3 taken from https://samplelib.com/sample-mp3.html.

```
library(shiny)

addResourcePath("Music", "Music")
audio_file1 <- "Music/sample-3s.mp3"

ui <- fluidPage(

  basicPage(
    tags$div(id = "AUDIO_MY"),
    selectInput("STH", "STH", 1:10, 1)
  )

)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(req(input$STH == "1"), {
    insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file1, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = NA, controls = NA, style="display:none;")
    , immediate = TRUE)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but didn't work. Also, if there is no `play` button in the UI, what should go in the `selector`?

Comment: The simplest solution will be to use `tags$body(tags$audio(src = audio_file1, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA, style="display:none;"))` without insertUI.

Comment: Other to put tags$div("ID") in the UI and later insert the audio to this div

Comment: I tried the `tags$body` suggestion, still does not work. May be `observeEvent` is not relevant without an action button?

Comment: I updated the answer and give u a working app.